# R - Group based on time steps and average all values included in them

Tags: r, dataframe

I have tables like the one below.

```
df <- data.frame(Metric = c("Stat1", "Stat1", "Stat1", "Stat1",
                            "Stat2", "Stat2", "Stat2",
                            "Stat3", "Stat3", "Stat3", "Stat3"),
                 Timestamp = c("0.000514", "0.060709", "0.091062", "0.134333",
                               "0.000382", "0.060018", "0.133970",
                               "0.007462", "0.078792", "0.115623", "0.148771"),
                 Value = c("10", "20", "25", "30",
                           "11", "21", "31",
                           "12", "22", "32", "37"))
```

There are multiple metrics and timestamps. Naturally for each timestamp there is a value for that metric. The problem is that between metrics the timestamps are completely different. It would be easier for me to work with the data if I have the same timestamps. I found that the average timestamp is 0.05533.

This is the result I'm trying to get.

```
df_new <- data.frame(Metric = c("Stat1", "Stat1", "Stat1",
                                "Stat2", "Stat2", "Stat2",
                                "Stat3", "Stat3", "Stat3"),
                     Timestamp = c("0.00", "0.05", "0.10",
                                   "0.00", "0.05", "0.10",
                                   "0.00", "0.05", "0.10"),
                     Value = c("10", "22.5", "30",
                               "11", "21", "31",
                               "12", "22", "34.5"))
```

I want to have the same timestamps for every metric. Starting with time 0, I want to average all values of a metric that are in the [0s,0.5s] range (then [0.5, 1.0s] and so on).

One issue is that there might be only one value for a metric in that range or multiple. It's not set.

How can I create the second table from the first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

v <- c(0,0.05, 0.1)

df %>%
  type_convert()%>%
  group_by(Metric, Timestamp = v[findInterval(Timestamp,v)])%>%
  summarise(Value = mean(Value))

# A tibble: 9 × 3
# Groups:   Metric [3]
  Metric Timestamp Value
  <chr>      <dbl> <dbl>
1 Stat1       0     10  
2 Stat1       0.05  22.5
3 Stat1       0.1   30  
4 Stat2       0     11  
5 Stat2       0.05  21  
6 Stat2       0.1   31  
7 Stat3       0     12  
8 Stat3       0.05  22  
9 Stat3       0.1   34.5
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case you can use `aggregate` and `floor` to round the timestamp to your desired values

Observe that the columns in your example are character strings thus i explicitly must convert it with as.numeric.

```r
df <- data.frame(Metric = c("Stat1", "Stat1", "Stat1", "Stat1",
                            "Stat2", "Stat2", "Stat2",
                            "Stat3", "Stat3", "Stat3", "Stat3"),
                 Timestamp = c("0.000514", "0.060709", "0.091062", "0.134333",
                               "0.000382", "0.060018", "0.133970",
                               "0.007462", "0.078792", "0.115623", "0.148771"),
                 Value = c("10", "20", "25", "30",
                           "11", "21", "31",
                           "12", "22", "32", "37"))

df2 <- aggregate(. ~ I(floor(as.numeric(Timestamp)/0.05)*0.05) + Metric, 
                 df, function(x) mean(as.numeric(x)))
df2
#>   I(floor(as.numeric(Timestamp)/0.05) * 0.05) Metric Timestamp Value
#> 1                                           0  Stat1 0.0005140  10.0
#> 2                                        0.05  Stat1 0.0758855  22.5
#> 3                                         0.1  Stat1 0.1343330  30.0
#> 4                                           0  Stat2 0.0003820  11.0
#> 5                                        0.05  Stat2 0.0600180  21.0
#> 6                                         0.1  Stat2 0.1339700  31.0
#> 7                                           0  Stat3 0.0074620  12.0
#> 8                                        0.05  Stat3 0.0787920  22.0
#> 9                                         0.1  Stat3 0.1321970  34.5
```

**edit**

If you want to improve legibility:

```r
df$Timestamp  <- as.numeric(df$Timestamp)
df$Value      <- as.numeric(df$Value)
df$Time_range <- floor(df$Timestamp/0.05)*0.05

df2 <- aggregate(. ~ Time_range + Metric, df, mean)

df2
#>   Time_range Metric Timestamp Value
#> 1       0.00  Stat1 0.0005140  10.0
#> 2       0.05  Stat1 0.0758855  22.5
#> 3       0.10  Stat1 0.1343330  30.0
#> 4       0.00  Stat2 0.0003820  11.0
#> 5       0.05  Stat2 0.0600180  21.0
#> 6       0.10  Stat2 0.1339700  31.0
#> 7       0.00  Stat3 0.0074620  12.0
#> 8       0.05  Stat3 0.0787920  22.0
#> 9       0.10  Stat3 0.1321970  34.5
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I like this solution. On a side note: `aggregate(Value~., transform(type.convert(rev(df), as.is = T), Timestamp = Timestamp %/% 0.05 *0.05), mean)`

Comment: The `rev` is not compulsory

Comment: Very elegant and concise. Thanks!

Comment: I have some questions. In reality, the dataframe is more complex. i) There are two more columns. ii) In some cases the timestep is bigger than 0.05 so there is no value for certain timesteps. This leads to df2 having the timerange and the Metric columns with correct values, but all the other columns are filled with NAs. 
1) Is that an issue of the extra columns or the timesteps > 0.05 for some metrics?
2) Would it be possible for the metrics/cases with the bigger timesteps to have an average of the two timesteps surrounding it or would that be too complex? Thanks.

Comment: Just tested a timestep of 0.1. If I keep the two extra columns (Category, Benchmark), then the problem with all but 2 columns (Time_range, Metric) containing only NA values remains. If I remain the two extra columns (Category, Benchmark), then the program behaves as expected.